# If group by (int) than group by (varchar) has better performance?

Tags: t-sql, group-by, sqlperformance

Suppose I have a table like

```
Mytaba(aid, int, name varchar(12),...)
myTabb(bid, aid, ...)
```

Then I have 2 SQL with group like to get same result:

```
Select aid,sum(...) 
from Mytaba a join mytabb b on a.aid = b.aid
group by aid

Select a.name,sum(...) 
from Mytaba a join mytabb b on a.aid = b.aid
group by a.name
```

Question: if group by(int) has better performance then group by(varchar)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both are indexed int would have an advantage as it is smaller.
More rows are in the same amount of memory,
With the join the query must access aid anyway.

Those two would only be equivalent if both aid and name are each unique.

In the myTabb an index on aid would help
Or if that is a composite key then the order aid, bid would probably result in an index seek rather than scan - a good thing and you would not need a separate index on aid.